# Number of Possible Configurations

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

I have an embarrassingly simple problem that I'm not confident that I'm answering correctly.

Say you have a 3 by 3 grid, where any number of spaces in the grid can be colored in, including all or none. What is the total number of possibilities? I was thinking it was 9!, or 362,880 possibilities. But that strike me as not correct.

Additionally, what would be the total number of possibilities assuming the grid can be rotated?

[image]

In that picture, assuming that only 1 being highlighted is the same as only 4, 64, or 256 being highlighted. Or that the set {1,32} would be identical to {4,128}, {256,8}, or {64,2}.

I don't imagine it's a quarter of the total possibilities from the first part, but this is outside of my normal math problems.

Comment: So you only have two colors?

Comment: Yes, black or white (really more on or off, but binary positions for each space).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first question, each of the $9$ squares independently has $2$ options, to be coloured or not to be coloured, so by the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) there's a total of $2^9=512$ ways to colour them.

The second question is slightly more difficult. There's something cool called [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma) that allows you to count these patterns by counting how many patters would be left unchanged by the various rotations.

In the present case, there are four operations allowed: do nothing, rotate by $90°$, rotate by $180°$ or rotate by $270°$. All $512$ patterns are left unchanged by doing nothing. For a pattern to be left unchanged under $90°$ rotation, all corners have to be the same and all sides have to be the same. That leaves only $3$ options (corners, sides, centre), for a total of $2^3=8$ (again the rule of product). For a pattern to be left unchanged under $180°$ rotation, all pairs of opposite squares have to be the same. There are $4$ of those, and the unpaired centre, so that leaves $5$ choices, for a total of $2^5=32$. A rotation by $270°$ is the same a rotation by $90°$ in the other direction, so that's $2^3=8$ again.

Then by Burnside's lemma, the number of types of patterns inequivalent under rotations is

$$
\frac14(512+8+32+8)=140\;,
$$

where the $4$ is the number of operations. So your guess of $\frac{512}4=128$ wasn't all that far off after all.

Comment: Good grief - yes that makes perfect sense. For some reason I was over complicating this tremendously.

Comment: So then, if I were to add the option of using a mirror image in combination with any of the four rotation options, would I simply change 1/4 to 1/8 for a total of 70?

Comment: @JesseWilliams: No, you'd have to go through the $8$ operations in the same manner as I did. We have the same $4$ operations, and $4$ more mirror operations (mirroring along the horizontal, vertical and diagonal lines through the centre), each of which has $3$ unpaired squares and $3$ pairs of squares, and thus $2^6=64$ invariant patterns. Thus in this case there are

$$\frac18(512+8+32+8+64+64+64+64)=102$$

different types of patterns.

Comment: Not quite as much gain, but still not bad. Thank you a ton! Now I have something new to read up on (Burnside's lemma).

Comment: Another dumb question, how would you verbalize $8$?

Comment: @JesseWilliams: Not sure I understand what you mean (since your English seems native) -- "eight"?

Comment: Sorry, the dollar signs. I've seen notation like that before, $4$, $8$, et cetera, but I'm not sure what it means. Or maybe it's something the iOS app version of SE is doing to posts I'm looking at...

Comment: Hahah it is - the numerals are in a notation format that the app doesn't quite know how to parse. I guess I should be doing this from my computer.  /sigh